# Flexbox centering 2 images and scale image when viewport gets too small

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I am fiddling with this simple layout for a while now.

The goal is to utilize flexbox to center 2 images that resize when the screen gets to small because the images themself are rather large.

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

Also the body itself stays above the Footer element, but the content in the body overlaps the footer, do someone knows how to fix this maybe?

[image]

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img class="prijsimage" src="../../assets/images/example1.png">
    <img class="prijsimage" src="../../assets/images/example2.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```css
.imagecontainer{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I also tried this code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img class="prijsimage" src="../../assets/images/prijslijst_noback.png">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img class="prijsimage" src="../../assets/images/pijslijst_noback_wax.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.imagecontainer{
    flex: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-top: 5%;
}

.prijsimage{
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.row{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .row {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  
    .imagecontainer {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      
    }
  
    .prijsimage {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 75vh;
      min-width: 0;
    }
  }
```

I really hopes that brings clarity of my issue. Can someone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `flex-direction: column;` to the container in your media query.  I cleaned up your code and made it as vanilla as possible so you can copy and paste into your project.

```css
.block {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
    padding: 1em;
    flex: 0 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: red solid;
}

/* Changed the max-width for testing purposes */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">content 1</div>
  <div class="block">content 2</div>
  <div class="block">content 3</div>
  <div class="block">content 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick anwser, but this does not fix it completely.

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin what else do you need?

Comment: can we chat so i can explain it with more images?

Comment: The image when in desktop resolution is stretched out over the whole website

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin like I stated in my solution, this is a very bare-bones solution that gives you the framework to work with. It's impossible for me to know what dimensions you are looking to use based on your screenshots. You will need to set a container width on `.container` and define the width of the images if you want to constrain them.